# How can I launch com.android.soundrecorder and start recording from ADB?

Tags: android, audio, adb

As the title suggests, I want to launch the soundrecorder which comes with my build of the android system and start recording a wav file and save it to either a default directory or one at my choosing.

With a little research I decided there is a (stupid) way to do it.

It has something to do with A. the monkey tool and B. the "input tap x,y". So basically I will first monkey-open the app, then tap the right set of buttons to start recording using the "input tap" command.

Now because I will do everything scripted, and the device**s** that I'm gonna run the script on is going to have an indefinite orientation **&** resolution, I will practically have to find out every single coordinates under every single condition to achieve my goal.

So I'm trying to see if there are better ways to do this, also here's the source code of what I believe to be the standard? build of this app:

[Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/SoundRecorder/+/master/src/com/android/soundrecorder/SoundRecorder.java)

How can I get it down?

Comment: You can use Uiautomator to perform the same steps, though it requires little bit of python/Java understanding. https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator

Comment: Hi, I take it that you don't need to know where those buttons are to "push" them?

Comment: you will only need "text"/"resouce-Id"/"Description" to click on a button. It does not require coordinates at all.

Comment: But I still have to install an APK right?

Comment: yes , for UIautomator test application based on Ui elements only

Comment: Shame! Then it complicate things a bit further even, as one of the reason that I 'm asking this question is because that I do not wish to install new apps. I thought you can simply "inject" the script into some process and get things done.